# Run `sass --watch` within SublimeText

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I've been working on a way to speed up my workflow with SublimeText2 and Sass.

I was looking for a way to have ST2 compile my SASS when I save. In looking how to do this, I came across this package: https://github.com/bnlucas/SassBuilder

In execution, it is exactly what I wanted, but it does not compile SASS like I hoped (doesn't include partials support).

So after more research I found a build package that works for me:

```
{

  "cmd": ["sass --watch 'index.scss':'index.css'", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"],
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }

}
```

This is similar to running the following command in a cmd prompt with Ruby:

```
sass --watch index.scss:index.css --stop-on-error --no-cache
```

So I run this build system and it watches my `index.scss` just fine. Any changes made to any of the .scss files in that folder and it updates the `.index.css` file. All of the standard messages from Sass are displayed in ST's console.

My issue is I know that is not what ST's build systems are for. Ideally, they would be used to build with a set of tools multiple times in a coding session.

#### My question is: How can I use ST2 to launch a `sass --watch` and have it run in the background? Is there some sort of command/key binding I could set to run the build's `cmd` line (`"cmd": ["sass --watch 'index.scss':'index.css'", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"]`)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`SublimeOnSaveBuild`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeOnSaveBuild) plugin, available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). Since you already have a working build system, all you need to do is configure the plugin to point to your `.sublime-build` file, modify the file endings if you want, and you should be all set.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think this does what OP wanted.  `sass --watch` *already* automatically builds on save, so he doesn't need a plugin to achieve that.